# Delete Object and its related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

Does anyone know how to delete an object and all of it's related entities.

For example I have tables, Products, Category, ProductCategory and productDetails, the productCategory is joining table of both Product and Category.

I have read from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738580.aspx that

> Deleting the parent object also deletes all the child objects in the
>   constrained relationship. This result is the same as enabling the
>   `CascadeDelete` property on the association for the relationship.

I am using this code:

```
Product productObj = this.ObjectContext.Product.Where(p => p.ProductID.Equals(productID)).First();

if (!productObj.ProductCategory.IsLoaded)
    productObj.ProductCategory.Load();

if (!productObj.ProductDetails.IsLoaded)
    productObj.ProductDetails.Load();

//my own methods.
base.Delete(productObj);
base.SaveAllObjectChanges();
```

But I am getting an error on `ObjectContext.SaveChanges();` I.e.,

> A relationship is being added or deleted from an `AssociationSet` 'FK_ProductCategory_Product'. With cardinality constraints, a corresponding 'ProductCategory' must also be added or deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I have solved my problem. Using the same cascade in EDMX.
For the explanation i am answering my own question. :)

We have to add `<OnDelete Action="Cascade"></OnDelete>` in EDMX file at two portions

1. In SSDL portion
2. In CSDL portion

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416478/ms-entity-framework-delete-child-onject/2417375#2417375). 
There the case of one-level association is described. In case you set the OnDelete action appropriately there should be no problems to delete all associated child objects.

Comment: This is generally right (+1), but you should really have a DB cascade if you do this.

Answer (score 3):

Also, If you look at your edmx file in visual studio, you can select the "association" and select "End1 OnDelete" property and set to "Cascade".

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that you need to ensure that objects are loaded for them to be deleted - I turned on Cascade but it didn't help until I had the required objects loaded (interestingly I also didn't need the Cascade turned on at all in my case).  I've documented details on the post that helped me the most in tracking down the details [Entity Framework delete child object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416478/entity-framework-delete-child-object/11821002#11821002)