# EF Delete Child Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I've the following:

```
class City {
    int id;
    string Name;
    ICollection<Person> Persons;
}

class Person {
   int id;
   string Name;
}
```

Which is the correct way to delete a City and all related Person?
Possibly I'd like to avoid foreign key constraint and do it manually.
I've tried:

```
public bool Delete(int id // City Id)
{
    City city = _db.Cities
                .Include(c => c.Persons)
                .First(c => c.Id == id);
    if(city != null)
    {
        foreach (Person person in city.Persons)
        {
            _db.Persons.Remove(person);
        }

        _db.Cities.Remove(city);

        _db.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

But no person or city are being removed from the database.

Comment: Are you ever getting a city at all? What happens when you step through?

Comment: What's happening when you debug? Are you even entering the foreach?

Comment: Side note: if you use `First()` city cannot be null. It throws an exception when the city does not exist. Could you answer the questions above?

Comment: You can have look at it. It may give you hint:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468027/entity-framework-delete-object-and-its-related-entities

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct...

You could also try using below code to delete entities:

```
foreach (Person person in city.Persons)
{
    _db.Persons.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}

_db.Cities.Entry(city).State = EntityState.Deleted;

_db.SaveChanges();
```

One more thing...

If you use `First` to get the `City` then the `if` statement will always be `true` since `First` expects to have a match and it throws an `InvalidOperationException` when the source sequence is empty.

Looking at your code I can see that the method returns `true` if there was a match by `id` and the deletion was performed, if there was no match it returns `false`. For `city` to be `null` you should use `FirstOrDefault`, it returns the default value of the type handled if the source sequence is empty, which in your case would be `null`.