# Delete entities in EF that are related

Tags: entity-framework

I have two entities. File and Binary. File contains file metadata and Binary contains file content. I want Binary instance be deleted when I remove File instance. I use the following:

```
public partial class MyEntities : Entities
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<File>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted))
        {
            entry.Reference<Binary>(i => i.FileBinary).EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This code does not work. I mean Binary instance is not deleted and also there is no error. Can anyone tell the reason or a better way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: If you enable `cascade deletion` for those tables, if `File` is your main table, it will delete related `Binary` table records of the deleting file record. You only need to delete the File record from your code and database will do the rest for you.

Comment: The Binary is the main table.

Answer (score 0):

You must add more details of your code, like your EF type(code first,model first,schema first) and etc. however if there is a relation between these two entities you can see this(it seems your entities are related, so if there is not relationship you can add it):

code first:
[Entity Framework: Delete Object and its related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468027/entity-framework-delete-object-and-its-related-entities)

model first and schema first:
[Cascading deletes](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/code-sample-cascading-deletes)

Comment: I'm using DB first and the entities are related. Binary is the parent and File is the child. Binary table holds binary content of files of this table and other tables.

Comment: @IranianCuriousBoy Look at the second link

Comment: I'm not a beginner. I work with File entity and I want related Binary entity be deleted when I delete File entity. The problem is that Binary is the parent and File is the child. Cascading means when I delete a parent record, the related children records be deleted. In this case the relation is inverse.