# RemoveAll() and Remove() not working on one to many relationship

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a one to many relationship between `HouseHolds` and `Invites`. One `HouseHold` to many `Invites`. I want to delete an invite from the table after 7 days from when the invite was sent. I'm not getting an error but the expired invites are still in the table. I tried `RemoveAll()` earlier with no luck. I'm new to this and don't know another method to try, any suggestions?

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
var hh = db.HouseHolds.Find(id);
var invList = hh.Invites.ToList();
foreach (var i in invList)
{
    if (DateTime.Compare(i.InviteDate.Date.AddDays(7).Date, dt) < 0)
        hh.Invites.Remove(i);
}
```

Comment: Did you call `SaveChanges` method from your context after that?

Comment: @octavioccl I used it earlier, its commented out now

Comment: But you need to call that method at the end if you want to persist those changes on your DB

Comment: I uncommented SaveChanges and got this error

Comment: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Comment: OK, that is another thing, now the problem is you are going to let those invites as orphans, so, you have two options: delete those invites from your database or you asign a different FK value to them, oh as a third option you can change that FK as nullable, but I don't know if that is possible in your model

Comment: @cSimms I believe you have to [set the entity state to `Deleted` as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620422)

Comment: @octavioccl I can't change the FK as nullable, each invite needs a HouseHoldId. I definitely want to delete the unused/expired invites from the invite table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the FK property is non-nullable in your `Invite` table you can't just remove the relationship calling `Remove` method from `Invites` navigation property.The problem is those entities will be orphans after that operation. One option to solve this problem is overriding your `SaveChanges` method:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
     Invites
        .Local
        .Where(r => r.HouseHold== null)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(r => Invites.Remove(r));

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or you can also change the state of those entities as `Deleted` in your cycle:

```
foreach (var i in invList)
{
  if (DateTime.Compare(i.InviteDate.Date.AddDays(7).Date, dt) < 0)
  {
     hh.Invites.Remove(i);
     db.Entry(i).State = EntityState.Deleted;
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much @octavioccl and @D Stanley