# Deleting Entity in Many to Many Relationship Leaves Orphans in Relationship Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

When deleting records that are in a many to many relationship, the relationship table has orphan records. I have the following many to many relationship set up in my DbContext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
     .HasMany(u => u.Owners)
     .WithMany(l => l.Cars)
     .Map(ul =>
     {
       ul.MapLeftKey("CarId");
       ul.MapRightKey("OwnerId");
       ul.ToTable("CarOwners");
     });
}
```

My Owner model has virtual property Cars:

```
public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
```

My Car model has virtual property Owners:

```
public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
```

I delete a Car as follows (db is my DbContext, car is a Car model).

```
db.Cars.Remove(car);
db.SaveChanges()
```

When I delete a Car, I was expecting all records in the table CarOwners with that CarId to be deleted as well but this is not the case.  Any advice?

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416478/entity-framework-delete-child-object/2417375#2417375) will be helpfull

Comment: Is there no enforced FK constraint for the relationship between link table and Car table? The database should not allow to have records with CarId = 1 in the link table and no car with that Id = 1. Did you create the DB with EF? Or manually?

Comment: @Slauma - I set up the DB manually.  I did not have FK constraint, was being lazy thinking Entity would take care of it automagically.  Does my answer make any sense?

Comment: ef only takes care of it, if it also creates the database. If you set it up manually, ef actually won't care about any constraints at all. Your database is missing delete cascading.

Comment: Yes, I think it will work with the change in your answer. (EF does not enable cascading *UPDATE* though when it creates the DB, I don't know if it might have unwished surprises if you enable it manually. I'd remove the ON UPDATE CASCADE from your ALTER TABLE statement.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CarOwners]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Car_Owners] FOREIGN KEY([CarId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Car] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CarOwners]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Owner_Cars] FOREIGN KEY([OwnerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Owner] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

NOTE: If you are adding constraints to an existing table with data, you will have to make sure that orphan records are removed first... or else the `ADD CONSTRAINT` will fail.